# Is there a way to lock viewport height after initialization using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am using 100vh for the height of a photo on a landing page. However, when I make the viewport's height smaller, the photo gets smaller also. Is there a way to have a fixed height (e.g. similar to when you set a height using px) but that sets as the height of the viewport when you first navigate to the website? The only way I want the height to change is if the page is refreshed. See below for a photo of the landing page and the photo (on the right) and my css so far as well (i.e. for the container that affects placement of the photo and the photo styling itself).

Essentially, it would be "height: (Initial Browser Height)px" and I should be able to scroll up and down if I make the viewport height smaller during navigation.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .model-photo {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[image: Landing Page]

Comment: is JavaScript allowed?

Comment: If Javascript is the best way to do it, give it a shot! I assumed I could do this with CSS, but I am open to figuring it out otherwise as well.

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @rraallvv I didn't, actually!